# Where is RESTful API parameter URL-decoded?

Tags: spring, rest, urldecode

I have a Spring-based RESTful API which is deployed to a Tomcat server. When I call this API like below (value of "para" has been URL-encoded) and debug it, value of "para" in controller method is "aaa bbb" which has already been URL-decoded.

- GET http://MY-TOMCAT-SERVER/SOME-PATH?para=aaa%20bbb

However, when I run a SpringBoot-based local Test Automation case (not deployed anywhere) to test the same API, the value of "para" in controller method hasn't been URL-decoded.

Question is, what is the difference between the two scenarios and where is "para" URL-decoded in the first scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I can give you a hint for the first part of your question:

The Apache Tomcat `server.xml` contains an tag `Connector`, this tag can have an optional attribute `URIEncoding`. Example:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000"
           port="8080"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

So I think that Tomcat is responsible for the URI encoding. But I do not know how this is activated in an Embedded-Spring-Boot-Tomcat.

- @See: [How does URIEncoding = 'UTF-8' work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054454/how-does-uriencoding-utf-8-work)
- @See: [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference / The HTTP Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: I didn't find such attribute configured in my Tomcat server.xml.

Comment: "If not specified, UTF-8 will be used unless the org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE system property is set to true in which case ISO-8859-1 will be used", so, the default attribute of "UTF-8" does the URL decoding here.

Comment: I do not know the actual default behaviour. But I have to set this property in some older Tomcat versions explicit to UTF-8 to turn on UTF-8 encoding.